# Realtime or regularly updated gravitational dataset(s) for Earth?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I need access to regularly updated gravitational readings from gravimeters around the globe.

Is there any such available dataset?

Comment: Here you can find a list of [gravity-related reports from USGS](https://mrdata.usgs.gov/catalog/science.php?thcode=2&term=1668). None of them are real time gravimetry, but if you read the metadata you will find out where they got the source data, and you may find contact information for the relevant people.

Answer (score 1):

You must start from here, from NASA site: https://earthdata.nasa.gov/learn/sensing-our-planet/matter-in-motion-earth-s-changing-gravity#ed-sop-datatable